# SQLite Connection GetConnection / Error

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I'm building an Cross platform app using Xamarin and Visual Studio 2017. I have problem with the connection to my database. So every time when I start my app it always crashes because of the connection to the database. Here is the code of my connection to the database.

```
public SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
{
    var filename = "database.db3";
    var documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
    var path = Path.Combine(documentsPath, filename);

    var connection = new SQLiteConnection (new SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid.SQLitePlatformAndroid(), "database.db3", true);
    return connection;
}
```

[image]

Any suggestion how I can solve this issue.
Thanks in advice.

Comment: What use are you making of the first three lines in the fourth line?

Comment: I'm about to include path variable instead of the filename. Actually i just did it but it's not working.

Comment: I think you should try to catch the exception caused by your code and report the exact error message received. The generic message displayed is of no help in debugging your application

Comment: Unhandled Exception:

SQLite.Net.SQLiteException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>


Message "Could not open database file: database.db3 (CannotOpen)" string

Comment: Try to replace the `"database.db3"` in your fourth line with `path` you got in your third line.

Comment: What error it shown when u debug? Is it null reference??

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if SQLite works differently in Xamarin Forms, but I use SQLite.NET (Frank Krueger's). Based on your sample above, All I see that is needed is to use the path variable that you created; you created the variable named "path" but you never used it to open the connection.

Here is a sample of how I did this in one of my Android (Not Forms) applications.

```
    public string DBPath
    {
        get
        {
          return Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "dbName.sqlite");
        }
    }
```

Then I create the SQLiteConnection like this:

```
 using (var dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection(DBPath))
            {
             ...                    
            }
```